# How to improve the accuracy on google analogy task while training word2vec models?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I have implemented a word2vec model(skipgram+negative sampling) only using Numpy, and I trained it on 300M English copera, and the model achieved an mediocre wordsim353 score about 0.5, but the accuracy on google analogy task is very bad, smaller that 0.1,how can I improve that?

As I observed, with more and more epochs, the wordsim353 score will improve abount 0.05 to 0.1 for each epoch, but the google analogy score only improves abount 0.01, I think it's weired.....

Is the embedding initialization presented in the paper matter? I initialized the embedding matrix by filling the matrix with the data sampled from a gassian(mean 0,variance 1) distribution....

The codes are written with Numpy.

```
model=[np.random.rand(vocab_size,embed_dim),np.random.rand(vocab_size,embed_dim)]
```

```py
def eval_analogy(inVecs,ques):
    analogy_a = ques[:,0] #(N,)
    analogy_b = ques[:,1]
    analogy_c = ques[:,2]
    analogy_d = ques[:,3]   
    nemb = normalize(inVecs,axis=1,norm='l2') 

    a_emb=nemb[analogy_a]  #(N,emb_dim)
    b_emb=nemb[analogy_b]
    c_emb=nemb[analogy_c]

    target=c_emb + (b_emb - a_emb) #(N,emb_dim)

    dist=np.matmul(target,nemb.T) #(N,vocab_size)
    pred_idx=np.argmax(dist,axis=1)  #(N,1)
    acc = (analogy_d == pred_idx).mean() 
    return acc

filepath='questions-words.txt'
token_to_idx=readfile('token_to_idx')
ques=read_analogies(filepath,token_to_idx)
print('input Vectors analogy:',eval_analogy(model[0],ques))
print('output Vectors analogy:',eval_analogy(model[1],ques))
```

I expected a high score but the actual output is `0.0864  0.0758`

Comment: Are you using your own word2vec implementation? (An off-the-shelf implementation, like the `Word2Vec` class in Python `gensim`, will be doing proper initialization, and includes helper methods for running the analogies-evaluation. Even if for some reason you wanted to use your own implementation, you may want to try the same text-corpus/metaparameters with a well-debugged off-the-shelf implementation – and then if your implementation tests much worse, that's strong evidence there are other bugs in your implementation/setup/testing.)

Comment: Yeah , I use my own word2vec implementation using Numpy, I want to ask that could there be such a situation that the score on wordsim353 is not too bad but the score on google analogy is bad? Is this situation normal in training word2vec? My code is  here , `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aSSfzR8ZL_L02y-0Ss2DoYKDmNZmBCY1`, I don't know whether there are some bugs espically about the function 'skipgram','loss','train'

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the 'wordsim353' evaluation, so don't know if that is a typical failure case. But, two correct word2vec implementations, trained with the same texts and same meta-parameters, should evaluate similarly (not identically) on things like the analogies-test. So you should check your implementation against others, and if the scoring on the exact same analogy-checking is very different, consider that a more definite sign of problems. (And, when your implementation can roughly match others, you can have more confidence in its proper functioning.)